# Overloading comparison operators for result types of three-way comparison operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, c++20

In C++20 we got a new three-way comparison `operator <=>` , which typically returns `std::strong_ordering` or `std::partial_ordering` types. And if class `A` has `operator <=>`, then the comparison of its objects `a1 < a2` is interpreted as `(a1 <=> a2) < 0`.

But can the user overload comparison operators, taking the first argument of type `std::strong_ordering` and the second argument accepting `0` literal? For example:

```
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>

struct A { 
    std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A &) const = default; 
};

void operator < (std::strong_ordering, std::nullptr_t) {
    std::cout << "overloaded< ";
}

int main() { 
    A{} < A{}; // #1
    (A{} <=> A{}) < 0; //#2
}
```

Here both GCC and Clang call overloaded `operator <`, even without any warning about the presence of another operator in the standard library. Is it ok? Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zEEP45Ezj

The behavior of MSVC is more interesting. In #1 it prints a weird error:

```
error C2088: '<': illegal for struct
```

In #2:

```
error C2593: 'operator <' is ambiguous
<source>(8): note: could be 'void operator <(std::strong_ordering,std::nullptr_t)'
C:/data/msvc/14.30.30423-Pre/include\compare(189): note: or       'bool std::operator <(const std::strong_ordering,std::_Literal_zero) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
<source>(14): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::strong_ordering, int)'
```

Personally I would prefer this behavior, but what is the right one here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard doesn't say anything about the *`unspecified`* type in `strong_ordering`'s comparisons, other than that it accepts the literal `0` exactly (and using anything else is undefined).

In particular, it doesn't specify the kind of implicit conversion sequence involved in converting the literal `0` to the parameter's type. If the implementation uses a class type for the parameter, then you get a user-defined conversion sequence that loses to your `operator<`'s standard conversion from `0` to `nullptr_t`; if it uses `nullptr_t` too, then it's ambiguous; if it uses `int`, then your overload loses.

Just...don't do it.